# Keras Multi-Label Classification 'to_categorical' Error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, multilabel-classification

Receiving

> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

when trying to create one-hot encoding using Keras to_categorical on output vectors. `Y.shape = (178,1)`. Please help (:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

# number of wine classes
classifications = 3

# load dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt('wine.csv', delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,1:14]
Y = dataset[:,0:1]

# convert output values to one-hot
Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y, classifications)

# creating model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(classifications, activation='softmax'))

# compile and fit model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", 
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=10, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem lies in the fact that `wine` labels are from range `[1, 3]` and `to_categorical` indexes classes from `0`. This makes an error when labeling `3` as `to_categorical` treats this index as an actual 4th class - what is inconsistent with the number of classes you provided. The easiest fix is to enumerate labels to start from `0` by:

```
Y = Y - 1
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it, however my network accuracy does not improve on the test set while training. Any idea why?

Comment: Well - there are many possible reasons. I'd try from making network narrower toward the input instead of becoming wider.

Comment: Up to 98%, added another couple hidden layers and narrowed network. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I know you answered this question long ago but I have a similar problem: my labels are [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10] (just an example, I have 25 classes) what should I do to make the label right for to_categorical?