# r keras: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_18 to have shape (None, 6)

Tags: r, keras

I am testing keras in r. 8 numeric predictors and a categorical response variable with 6 classes.

I know my example is nonsensical - but I just want to understand why keras is not running - why I am getting this error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_18 to have shape (None, 6) but got array with shape (1500, 7)

```
# Create an artificial example with a categorical response variable:
set.seed(123)
y <- sample(1:6, 2000, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(1234)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2000 * 8), nrow = 2000))
str(y)
str(x)

# Create a train-test split:
library(caret)
set.seed(12)
forTrain <- createDataPartition(y, p = 0.74887, list = FALSE)
x.train <- x[forTrain, ]
x.test <- x[-forTrain, ]
y.train <- y[forTrain]
y.test <- y[-forTrain]
dim(x.train)[1] == length(y.train)
length(y.train); length(y.test)

# Build network:
library(keras)
network <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 100, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(1 * 8)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = "softmax")

network %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

# Transform inputs:

x.train <- as.matrix(x.train)
x.test <- as.matrix(x.test)

x.train <- array_reshape(x.train, c(1500, 1 * 8))
x.test <- array_reshape(x.test, c(500, 1 * 8))

y.train <- to_categorical(y.train)
y.test <- to_categorical(y.test)

# Try to train:
network %>% fit(x.train, y.train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 25)
```

Or is the error because to_categorical creates for some reason 7 columns?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your labels are in the range [1, 7], but for `to_categorical` you should have the labels in the range [0, 6].

Same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397103/keras-multi-label-classification-to-categorical-error).

> The easiest fix is to enumerate labels to start from 0 by:
>        `Y = Y - 1`